# Is "smtp" the only valid name for smtp server?

Tags: email, smtp

Is `smtp` the only valid name for smtp server? Or any name is valid.

E.g.

Is valid this too:

```
mail9s2b.example.com
```

or only this:

```
smtp.example.com
```

The guy on the hosting support told me that only `smtp.example.com` os valid and `mail9s2b.example.com` is not.

Does he lie or he is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any normal name is valid. It does **not** have to be SMTP. Email.domain.tld is perfectly fine, as is IwasInaWeirdmoodToday.domain.tld.

The only important thing is that your mailserver is properly configured and that the MX records point to the server.

Having said that, using smtp as a host name for a smtp server is a lot clearer than mail. But that is only easier on the people. It is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

Any DNS name is appropriate for any machine, provided it does not violate URL naming rules (special chars, hierarchy, etc).

Unless he meant that you had to use that name due to previously configured machines, I don't think he is right.

See this [link](http://www.arclab.com/products/amlc/list-of-smtp-and-pop3-servers-mailserver-list.html) for at least two addresses of STMP servers without a SMTP preffix.